# Why does kill-region (C-w) only kill the region marked by the first cursor when using multiple cursors

Tags: multiple-cursors

Having selected five regions with five cursors using multiple-cursors-mode:

[image: Image showing five fields selected]

why is it that when I press `C-w` or `M-x kill-region` it is only done for the primary cursor?

[image: Image showing that only one region has been killed]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first time you run `kill-region` in multiple cursors mode, it asks `Do kill-region for all cursors?`.  I guess you accidentally replied `n` to that question - and multiple-cursors-mode remembers this answer forever.  You can check this by looking at the value of the variable `mc/cmds-to-run-once` (that is, type `C-h v` and the name of the variable).

To fix this, you could remove `kill-region` from `mc/cmds-to-run-once`:

```
(setq mc/cmds-to-run-once (delq 'kill-region mc/cmds-to-run-once))
```

And then save the command list to disk:

```
(mc/save-lists)
```

(You can run the two forms above from `M-x ielm`.)